# ibuffer: how to filter ruby and rspec buffer into separate groups?

Tags: ibuffer

I have files like `model.rb` and `model_spec.rb` in my Rails project. 
Both have ruby as major mode and using a regex doesn't work on the Specs filter group.

```
(setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
  (quote (("default"
            ("Ruby" 
              (mode . ruby-mode))
            ("Specs"
              (name . "spec\.rb$"))))))
```

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order? Like putting "Specs" before "Ruby"?

Comment: @Dimitry: Reversing the order puts my spec files into the right filter group but i like to have the ruby filter group on top of my ibuffer.

Comment: Okay, then I guess you'll need to use a predicate (see the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
      '(("default"
         ("Ruby"
          (predicate . (and (eq major-mode 'ruby-mode)
                            (not (string-match-p "spec\\.rb\\'"
                                                 buffer-file-name)))))
         ("Specs"
          (name . "spec\\.rb\\'")))))
```

Using a more complex check seems necessary, since you want `Ruby` to be at the top. I also fixed the spec regexp a bit (really escape the dot and use the "end of string" anchor instead of the "end of line").